# How do I add svg element to Imagick image?

Tags: php, svg, imagick

I'm trying to piece together a png from various components of an svg file using Imagick. I am able to get the text in and behaving as expected. Now how can I start adding the various svg components. In the example below, I have a sample variable with a string that represents my svg element. I have to use SVG element formatting and attributes, like `r`, may occasionally be set by variables.

Edit: Big picture, I'm just converting an svg with some dynamic settings to a png.

```
<?php

//SVG ELEMENT TO INCORPORATE
$element = '<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />';

//MESSAGE
$message = "Get this SVG to work.";

//FILENAME
$fileName = "testSVG" . microtime(true) . ".png";

//SET THE SIZE, BACKGROUND, AND FORMAT
$image = new Imagick();
$image->newImage(1200, 630, new ImagickPixel('pink'));
$image->setImageFormat('png');

//NEW DRAW ELEMENT
$draw = new ImagickDraw();

//FONT PROPERTIES 
$draw->setFont('Impact.ttf');
$draw->setFontSize(50);
$draw->setFillColor("red");
$draw->setStrokeAntialias(true);
$draw->setTextAntialias(true);

//FONT METRICS 
$metrics = $image->queryFontMetrics($draw, $message);

//ADD TEXT TO CANVAS 
$draw->annotation(5, $metrics['ascender']+5, $message);

//DRAW THE IMAGE
$image->drawImage($draw);

//SAVE THE IMAGE 
file_put_contents($fileName, $image);

//DISPLAY THE IMAGE
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;

?>
```

Comment: You've not explained very well what you're trying to do. But it sounds like you want to find yourself something that is purpose-built to create SVG files, and not the `Imagick` class.

Comment: @miken32 Before ImageTragick I was able to stitch together a full svg file by assembling various svg elements from different directories. I'd build a blank svg and populate it with strings that contained individual svg elements. Once assembled, the whole file was converted to a png. When the tragick fix was implemented, it broke the way I used to assemble things. [Here's an earlier related discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686984/imagetragick-fix-broke-my-script-and-not-sure-how-to-fix/37687980?noredirect=1#comment62854421_37687980) that fixed being able to add images and text.